# Is it possible to create and then get instance of Audioplayer by Id in just_audio flutter package?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

There is a same method in audioplayers package ( final player = AudioPlayer(playerId: 'my_unique_playerId');
Is there some similar in just_audio?

I need to get it in different parts of the application and it would be convenient to get it by id as in other players packages

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The answer would depend on whether the different parts of your application are in different isolates or not, so that is one way you could clarify your question.

Comment: @RyanHeise ,thank you for the request for clarification. The peculiarity is that I use FlatterFlow and although it seems that the level of isolate there is the same everywhere - but I can insert custom functions and widgets into different parts of the application and transfer between them only serializable objects through the shared_preferences package.  The other isolate is needed for music playback background as far as I understand.

Comment: Isolates is the only reason I could think of for why you need IDs. It sounds like you're not actually sure whether there are isolates involved. Either way, you need to "edit" your question and clarify why exactly you need IDs. In all likelihood you don't need IDs, and there will be a better way to accomplish your ultimate goal, but your question is currently too bare to be able to provide that advice.